# Looking at the same comment thrice

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

When a user comments on my answer or question I get notified in three distinct locations:

1. On the question page itself
2. In the top navigation bar
3. On my profile page

The problem is that the notifications 2 and 3 do not disappear when I already saw the comment by already being on the page itself or by clicking on the `1` in the navigation bar or on my profile. Chances are that I am reading the same comment three times.

Is it possible to remove the notifications on the profile page and on the top navigation bar when the comment is seen?

Comment: The notification in the top bar does disappear for me when I read the associated comment. Only the notification on the Responses tab in my profile remains.

Comment: I have a feeling the "Replies" tab doesn't look at individual comments to determine whether or not you've seen them. It's likely that this is just a `boolean` or possibly a "Last opened this tab" `date`.

Comment: It would be nice if at least the last 2 were synced. Also, if I can be a bit pedantic: t_h_rice not trice.

Comment: @theB yeah that really bugged me too, so I fixed that.

Comment: The number on the tab page means responses since the last time you've looked at the tab, so you're asking for the meaning of the number to be changed. The one thing I would say is that clicking on the timestamp of a comment should remove the notification from the topbar.

Comment: This irritates me as well. I agree it should be synced!

Comment: Only the comments must be synced and not the reputation. *I just love seeing the moar rep everywhere* :D